# Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Self.Element' and 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, sequence, swift4.1, xcode9.3, anyobject

I get the following error: **Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Self.Element' and 'AnyObject'** on the line: `return contains { $0 === object }`.

Is there a way to cast `object` to the type of `Iterator.Element`? Does the line `where Iterator.Element: AnyObject` not mean that that the `Iterator.Element` must be representable as `AnyObject`?

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: AnyObject {

    /**
     - Parameter object:
     */
    func containsObjectIdentical(to object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return contains { $0 === object }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug [SR-7275](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7275) (actually a regression). It should be already fixed in Xcode 9.3.1.

Just remove the `Iterator` from the `where` clause:

```
extension Sequence where Element: AnyObject {
    func containsObjectIdentical(to object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return contains { $0 === object }
    }
}
```

While `Self.Element` and `Self.Iterator.Element` for `Sequence` are the same, it seems the compiler cannot see the transitive equality.

Also, you might consider making the method type safe and only compare with objects of type `Element`:

```
extension Sequence where Element: AnyObject {
    func containsObjectIdentical(to object: Element) -> Bool {
        return contains { $0 === object }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for your help -- this seemed to fix the problem.